# access to environment variables in java

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

i want to do in my application a button that makes me enter in the list of environment variables in my system
like the example below to enter in file system

```
                   b = new Button(dialog, SWT.PUSH);
                 b.setText("Browse file system");
                   b.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    DirectoryDialog fileDialog = new DirectoryDialog(parent);
    fileDialog.setFilterPath(pathText.getText());
    String file = fileDialog.open();
    if (file != null) {
        File workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
            .getLocation().toFile().getAbsoluteFile();

        String workspacePath = workspace.toString();
        if (file.contains(workspacePath))
        file = file.replace(workspacePath, "$WORKSPACE")
            .replace("\\", "/");
        pathText.setText(file);
    }
    super.widgetSelected(e);
    }
});
```

can anyone helpen me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.getenv()` gives you a simple map of environment variables :

From [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) :

```
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvMap {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
        System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                          envName,
                          env.get(envName));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank your for your response, but i have another problem ,  i try with the fonction :

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that I can understand your question clearly, but there is a standard Oracle doc about working with env variables:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html